# Joining MySQL tables to include multiple duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, one with a series of strings in two columns, one with a series of attributes. I need to create a view to join them so that the strings can be married up to many attributes. For example:

```
Table1:

String1  |  String2
===================
aa11     |  abc123
bb22     |  def456
cc33     |  ghi789

Table2:

String1  |  Attribute1
===================
aa11     |  1
aa11     |  4
aa11     |  8
aa11     |  9
bb22     |  2
bb22     |  4
cc33     |  1
cc33     |  2
cc33     |  5
cc33     |  9

What I want at the end:

String1  |  Attribute1  |  String2
===================================
aa11     |  1           |  abc123
aa11     |  4           |  abc123
aa11     |  8           |  abc123
aa11     |  9           |  abc123
bb22     |  2           |  def456
bb22     |  4           |  def456
cc33     |  1           |  ghi789
cc33     |  2           |  ghi789
cc33     |  5           |  ghi789
cc33     |  9           |  ghi789
```

What kind of join is this? What is the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a normal join query:

```
select t1.string1, t2.attribute1, t1.string2 
    from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on (t1.string1 = t2.string1)
```

You can see the [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b15c54/2) here.

Also, try to learn more about `SQL Joins` over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: That seems to work a charm! Not sure why it didn't work for me when I tried it. I'll go back over my steps to see what I did wrong the first time, but thanks for clarifying.